# how to load or get image by folder from photo library in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary

i want to do something which help is not available on net. so i am asking here. The problem is that i want to load images or want to give the option to iPhone user to select images by folder like if i select the folder then whole images of the folder should load from photo library to in my application.As far now i only saw the option of loading single image using native controller or multiple selection using 3rd party controller. But i didn't found any thing by which i can select or load images by folder so can any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

After long wait and for a lot of the search i decided to make my own control so i modified the
[Elcimagepickerviewcontroller](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController) and modified to select or load images by album [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/thl9fhungbh9l0z/ELCImagePickerController-master%202.zip) is the modified code now user can select images by album :) .